# Picking a crankset for a 107mm BB on a downhill bike

Tags: crankset, downhill

I bought a downhill frame (Commencal DH Supreme 2012) that I want to build up with parts myself.
Now I'm trying to pick a suitable crankset for the 107mm bottom bracket. Having a hard time finding anything. It seems like not even the Saint group supports 107mm BBs. Where should I start searching? I'm not looking for specific advice but I need to find a place start or maybe I'm not getting it right with the specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the tech sheet at http://www.commencal-store.co.uk/PBSCProduct.asp?ItmID=12450127 you need a Press-fit BB.

PF107 should have 41mm diameter cups, have the same overall width as an External-bearing BB in an 83mm shell, and be compatible with the same cranks as "normal" external-83mm BBs.

SM-BB71 should work in your frame, and allow you to fit FC-M815 cranks. The cups will be the same as the "73mm" pressfit BBs, but the inner cover (aka spacer tube) is longer for "83mm".

Comment: you are right, those are internal press in bearings, so the total width is about the same as the regular ones. thanks for the reply, helped a lot.